# Calling Python file with command line arguments from another python file

Tags: python

Currently my python code is called from command line as follows:

```
C:\project-master>python myFile.py --plugin TestPlugin\migration -f "C:/Form1/All_2020-01-01.xsd"
```

Where myFile.py code needs commandline arguments:

```
--plugin TestPlugin\migration
-f "C:/Form1/All_2020-01-01.xsd"
```

I have created a new python file called: `Test.py`. From `Test.py` file, how can I make a call to `myFile.py` along with the required arguments. For example-

```
class Workflow:

    def Process(self):
        # How to make a call for below commandline from here: 
        # myFile.py --plugin TestPlugin\migration -f "C:/Form1/All_2020-01-01.xsd"

A = Workflow()
A.Process()
```

Comment: Why not import the functionality and invoke it directly?

Comment: Please can you show how to import and invoke with arguments

Comment: Well you haven't shown the code you're trying to call, so not really. But any decent tutorial will cover importing code and calling classes and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python subprocess module is your friend on this one.

You can use the `run()` function of the `subprocess` module. Your execution command is given as a list of strings as the first arugment in `run()`

So in your case it should look like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "myFile.py", "--plugin", "TestPlugin\migration", "-f", "C:/Form1/All_2020-01-01.xsd"], shell=False)
```

You can put that line into your `Process()` method.

Also have a look in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if you want to catch the output e.g.

Comment: Awesome! this is what I was looking for and it worked for me.